# Unity 3d build failed almost at the end, but it run fine in editor why is that?

Tags: unity-game-engine, crash, build.gradle

Why my unity build is failing at the last moment??? I can run the game fine in editor but it won't build the release version, does anyone know why?
I have already setup keystore and I am using default unity sdk and ndk.

[image: Here is the Errors I am getting]

Comment: There's nothing in that screen shot that can help diagnose your issue. I'd suggest editing a text version of the failure into your question. You're looking for the part of the log that shows `stderr` from the build process.

Answer (score 0):

you have 4 errors and you can see their solutions in the links below:

Try to solve it one after another because maybe the first problem leads to all other problems.

unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE : [Solution 1](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues/1269)

Compiling Error: Major Version 52 is newer than 51 : [Solution 2](https://forum.unity.com/threads/compiling-error-major-version-52-is-newer-than-51.412478/)

CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed : [Solution 3](https://forum.unity.com/threads/commandinvokationfailure-gradle-build-failed.479460/)

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr) : [Solution 4](https://forum.unity.com/threads/unityengine-guiutility-processevent-int32-intptr.514797/)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that having any special characters in the full path that leads to Unity project folder will crash Unity WebGL build at the end every time.

Project will run without errors in the Unity Editor, but crash constantly if there is e.g. comma in the path name.

In this case there was a path like:

```
Homefolder/Create with code, name/ProjectFolder
```

which kept crashing constantly.

Changing the path to this:

```
Homefolder/Create_with_code_name/ProjectFolder
```

solved the issue.

What is notable that the ***ProjectFolder*** itself didn't have any special characters in it but the folder that lead to this folder.